# React Native: Version code too big for Android using enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I was compiling my React Native App for Android having **enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture** to false but since I read if I set to true, then the app will reduce like 4mb and it's true.

So my current version code was 9 so I set to 10 the new one and when I created a new release with that option to **true** I uploaded it to my Google Play dashboard and I realised the new version code is not 10 but is 1048586 :/

Fortunately I don't published that version and I just removed it but I'm wondering what happened and if that's normal and if I create a new version after that, the number will increate just 1 unit like 1048586 to 1048587?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found the line of code that set the version code

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

But still I couldn't find the real reason about why it's necessary to increase the version code to a big number

Comment: You don't need to change it to a big number, just to something bigger than the previous version.  Standard practice is to increase it by one for each version.

Comment: But do you know why the Android documentation and the React Native code is doing that... multiply with a large number only when you are generating a separate build for x86 and for arm?

Comment: If that code you posted is from react native then no I don't know why they would do that.

Comment: Android is doing the same, this link is in that code http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits

Comment: Yeah I don't know.  That's an example of bad programming because the comments just explain what the code is doing, but not why.  I can see what the code is doing from reading the code, but I'm left in the dark why it's doing that - which is what code comments are for.  Bad Google.

Comment: Yes at least a short explanation will be good.

Answer (score 1):

"We need this because each APK in the ABI requires a separate version code which goes up each time the app updates. This code block adds a different constant for each architecture to your base version code. Each APK then get their own distinct values which are unlikely to overlap. For more details take a look at the Android documentation for ABI splits."

https://reactnative.thenativebits.com/courses/upgrading-react-native/upgrade-to-react-native-0.59/

Therefore you need to "give up control" of your versionCode to the build system and rely on the versionName instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you multiplied with a small number .... like say 2.

So apk version codes for  ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2] will be

When you set the android: default version code to be 1:

- armeabi-v7a: 1 * 2 + 1 = 3
- x86: 2 * 2 + 1 = 5

Let's say you have another release now and decide to to use default version code to be 2. Hence version codes for architectures:

- armeabi-v7a: 1 * 2 + 2 = 4
- x86: 2 * 2 + 2 = 6

Now in the next release when you use default version code of 3, you'll notice that we run into issues. Here, version codes for architectures:

- armeabi-v7a: 1 * 2 + 3 = 5 **(CONFLICTS with x86 version code for 1st release)**
- x86: 2 * 2 + 3 = 7

**PS:** The above answer is solely based on my understanding/interpretation and the original authors could very well have had an entirely different reason.

Answer (score 0):

change - **def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture** from true to false after that whenever you create a build it should be increment with +1 only.